# how to save/retrieve data image/text into android xml file

Tags: android-xml

I am building one feature of a fishing app.I will need to store picture and description of species of fish found in various lakes of my state. I will display a list view of those species and allow the user to choose which one to display. What is the best option to store and retrieve the data (species picture and description) I understand I can use a xml strings. How can I setup my xml string to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you need:
-a ListView showing species,
onClick: show new View with details of the selected species with photo.
And all this, from an XML?

If you're using a local XML file inserted in the assets you can use a Parser to Parse the data from the XML to Objects.

Then in the activity, you create a listview using the species objects.
Add an OnItemClickListener to the listview to determine who is clicked.
show a new view with the details of the selected species.

If you want extra information, ask ahead :) I hope this was helpful